Azure Linux WebApp Directory password
Have tried the answer in How to: Password Protect Azure App service but in my wordpress-linux-appservice container it is not working. Main issue i found is nginx service is stopped while my wordpress content are being served without any issue.
1df0ea390fee:~# netstat -tlnp | grep -E '(:80|:443)'
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      232/nginx: master p 
1df0ea390fee:~# ^C
1df0ea390fee:~# rc-service nginx status
* status: stopped

Tried the answer for Linux Azure WebApp solution...but running into the issue , nginx is stopped.

To password protect a directory in your Azure Linux WebApp running a WordPress container with Nginx, you need to create a .htpasswd file and update your nginx.conf to use this file for authentication.
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget gnupg gnupg2 apache2-utils && \
    wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb-release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx supervisor php7.4-fpm


RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default


COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/


COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf


EXPOSE 80 443


CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]

Update your nginx.conf to include the directives for HTTP Basic Authentication
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

edit your supervisord.conf
[supervisord]

nodaemon=true

  

[program:nginx]

command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"

stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/access.log

stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/error.log

autorestart=true

  

[program:php-fpm]

command=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4

stdout_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm.log

stderr_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm.log

autorestart=true

Rebuild the image with the updated Dockerfile and run the docker container with the newly built image
docker build -t wordpress-nginx .

docker run -d -p 8081:80 wordpress-nginx


Set Up HTTP Basic Authentication Inside the Container
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash



